# Why can't I input the name and it kept coming up again before age

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void input(void);
void avgSalary(void);

struct Person{
    char name[15];
    int age;
    float salary;
};

struct Person person[10];

int main(){
    int choice, avg;
    char cont;
    
    do{
        printf("1. Input person record \n2. Average salary\n");
        printf("\nPlease enter selection: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        if (choice == 1){
            input();
        }
        else if (choice == 2){
            avgSalary();
        }
        else{
            printf("Error");
        };
        printf("\nContinue?: ");
        scanf("%c", &cont);
        printf("\n");       
    }while(toupper(cont)=='Y');
}

void input(){
    int x;
    getchar();
    for (x=0;x<10;x++){
        printf("Person %d\n", x+1);
        printf("Name: ");
        gets(person[x].name);
        printf("Age: ");
        scanf("%d", &person[x].age);
        printf("Salary: ");
        scanf("%f", &person[x].salary);
    };
}

void avgSalary(){
    int x, sum=0;
    float avg=0;
    for (x=0;x<10;x++){
        sum += person[x].salary;
    };
    avg = sum/10;
    printf("The average salary of %d person is %.2f\n", x, avg);
}
```

For the output, It asks for person's info and another is the average salary. We select 1 then after entering the first person's name, age and salary, I couldn't enter the next person's name all the way until the 10th person. Why is this happening?

Comment: it still doesn't work. I mean like when i wanted to enter the second person  name it skipped and show name: age:

Comment: The newline is not being consumed after call `scanf` on some of your calls, causing execution flow to _skip_ over some of your code.   `scanf("%c", &cont);` -> `scanf(" %c", &cont);`  (adding a space before `%c` removes any white space (blanks, tabs, or newlines))

Comment: _"It still doesn't work"_ is not very helpful.

Comment: Run the code in debugger with break points to see what is happening.  Then update your post with more specific information.

Comment: I would recommend replacing all `scanf()`, and `gets()`  calls with `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stding);`.  For strings, replace `buf` with corresponding string struct member.  For numbers, use `buf` as argument to either `strtol()` or `strtod()` calls to convert to number.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing `gets(person[x].name);` with `scanf` .You could try `scanf("%s",person[x].name);` . Or you could probably (not recommended) add a `getchar()` at the end of your loop,after the last `scanf` call. In your first run through the loop,you are getting the behavior you want because you use the `getchar()` that is being called before the loop.

Edit:

Keep in mind that,using `scanf` you can't take an input containing a full name. If you want to do that,you can either use a seperate array for the last name in your Struct.Or else you can just probably get away with using `getchar()` and `gets`.

Comment: That `scanf` will fail to read a name with spaces in it, reading only the first part of the name.

Comment: Allocating that little space made me believe he was only trying to keep only the first name,without the surname. Probably a more suitable  approach is to keep a seperate array in the struct containing the surname. But ,if both first name and lastname is needed, ```getchar()``` could be used as mentioned. @hyde